# Getting Error while running rails server - undefined method `blank_criteria' for class `Array' (NameError) from mongoid.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, activesupport

**Rails version 5.2.2**

**Ruby version 2.6.1**

**Mongoid version 8.0.2**

I am using docker and there also I am getting same issue. Tried locally as well with rails s and getting same issue there. Its not allowing rails db:create. I have application.rb file where mongoid module is included. In mongoid.rb file some customized methods are written to convert ids into string.

**Error** :

```
    26: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    25: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    24: from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    23: from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    22: from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    21: from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    20: from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    19: from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    18: from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    17: from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    16: from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
    15: from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `require'
    14: from /home/xxx/sites/demo/config/application.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /home/xxx/sites/demo/config/application.rb:11:in `require'
    12: from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mongoid-8.0.2/lib/mongoid.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mongoid-8.0.2/lib/mongoid.rb:24:in `require'
    10: from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mongoid-8.0.2/lib/mongoid/document.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mongoid-8.0.2/lib/mongoid/document.rb:5:in `require'
     8: from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mongoid-8.0.2/lib/mongoid/extensions.rb:35:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mongoid-8.0.2/lib/mongoid/extensions.rb:35:in `require'
     6: from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mongoid-8.0.2/lib/mongoid/extensions/array.rb:173:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mongoid-8.0.2/lib/mongoid/deprecable.rb:30:in `deprecate'
     4: from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/deprecation/instance_delegator.rb:22:in `deprecate_methods'
     3: from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/deprecation/method_wrappers.rb:57:in `deprecate_methods'
     2: from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/deprecation/method_wrappers.rb:57:in `each'
     1: from /home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/deprecation/method_wrappers.rb:67:in `block in deprecate_methods'
/home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/deprecation/method_wrappers.rb:67:in `alias_method': undefined method `blank_criteria' for class `Array' (NameError)
```

Any help on this will be appriciated.

**Mongoid.rb file is as follows:**

```
module Mongoid
  module Document
    def as_json(options={})
      attrs = super(options)
      attrs["id"] = attrs["_id"] = attrs["_id"].to_s
      attrs
    end
  end

  class Criteria
    def pluck_to_s(key)
      self.pluck(key).map {|id| id.to_s}
    end
  end
end
```

**application.rb file is as follows** :

```
require "active_model/railtie"
# require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require 'action_cable/engine'
require "sprockets/railtie"

require 'openssl'
require 'mongoid'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Demo
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.api_only = true

    config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
    Rails.configuration.action_controller.per_form_csrf_tokens = true
    config.middleware.use(Mongoid::QueryCache::Middleware)

    # For other Services
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{*/}')]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'enums', '{*/}')]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app/components/**/')]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'services', '{*/}')]

    # For eager load
    config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)

    config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :put, :delete, :options]
      end
    end

    config.cache_store = :redis_store, ENV.fetch('REDIS_URL')
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please also add your application.rb and mongoid.rb in the question?

Comment: @Vishal I have added the files in question itself now.

Comment: Anyone who is referring this kind of an error, this comment is for them. This issue has been resolved. The issue was due to version of mongoid gem. The gem version was 8.0.2 which was not compatible with ruby version 2.6.1, so I just downgraded the version to 7.0.1 and now this issue is gone. Everything working fine.